# Force footer in the MDL framework to stick to the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css

So there are many questions on how to make a footer stick, I tried some, but they didn't work, I think because the CSS from the framework I'm using make sit a different use case. I'm using Google's Material Design Lite
: http://www.getmdl.io/index.html.

Here is a fiddle that shows the basic page layout: https://jsfiddle.net/zrqeskLk/.

What I'm after: If the page's content is less than the screen height, the footer sits at the bottom of the screen. If the page's content is greater than the screen height, the footer is append to the end of the page's content.

```
The <footer> tag cannot be moved to the final page element, if that is a suggestion.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written a small piece of jQuery for you, that will do exactly what you want.

```
//store the content's height and footer in variables
var contentHeight = $('.mdl-grid').height(),
footer = $('.mdl-mini-footer');
//Check content's height vs window-height
if (contentHeight < $(window).height()) {
    //add class that puts the footer at the bottom if the check is true
    footer.addClass('bottomstick');
} else {
    //remove class that puts the footer at the bottom if the check is false
    footer.removeClass('bottomstick');
}
```

This code needs some tweaking (it might act different when the content is just on the edge of being higher than the window for example), but it's a start you definitely will be able to continue with!

Try it out in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zrqeskLk/12/) by removing and adding the Lorem Ipsum I inserted under Hello World. You can also see I added a little bit of CSS so it actually sticks to the bottom.

Also, this code is purely checking on load of the page, not after that. So if a user resizes his/her window, it won't change the footer. This is easy to add though, but if you need help, let me know.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer, but it doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Have you added jQuery?

Comment: The class "bottomstick", where is the CSS?

Comment: Huh, it seems to have vanished, just a second.

Comment: @user1515024 I have updated the fiddle, it's the same link in the answer though :) Check it out! https://jsfiddle.net/zrqeskLk/12/

Comment: Thanks man, had to make a few small changes, but this works great! The if(contentHeight < $(window).height()) is comparing a string to an int, because $('.mdl-grid').css('height');  returns the height + 'px', but I fixed that. Cheers mate.

Comment: Oh, it shouldn't be doing that in version 12 of that fiddle, but good you found that :)